# Cannot remove Continue reading from the Twenty Twelve Blog Index Page

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove the Continue Reading "Post Title">> from each of the blog index page. But I am not able to do this.

I know that the Continue Reading is in the content.php of the Twenty Twelve Theme. Below is exactly how the code is:-

```
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span>&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
```

I have tried changing this to:-

```
<?php the_content( __( ' ', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
```

and even

```
 <?php the_content(); ?>.
```

But nothing works out. I have even tried to add some functions to the `functions.php` file as suggested in WP Function Reference and a lot of forums.

How can I remove this link all together from the index page? Even if I change the words from Continue Reading to something else like Read More in the content.php, no change appears in the Index page. I do not want to touch the core files of WP.

PS:-I have been clearing my browser cache as well.

Comment: try to comment this line.

Comment: http://whiteboard-it.com/business/hide-continue-reading-from-wordpress/

Comment: If I comment this line, neither the blog post appears in the single page nor does the excerpt appear in the index page. What appears is only the title. I need the part of the content before the read more but not the read more link.

Comment: Vikingben: I am using Twenty Twelve. Those functions in the link do not exist in the functions.php file of Twenty Twelve. So don't have anything to edit or add a class to.